# How do Android applications such as Facebook Messenger and Llama stay running in the background from boot time?

Tags: android, service, background, xamarin

I'm developing an application that uses a Bound Service to query information from a server and provide notifications when conditions are met. At the moment, the user must execute the application from their home screen in order to begin receiving updates. But, for example, applications like the Facebook Messenger and Llama run from the moment the phone starts in the background. How do I achieve similar functionality for my long-term application? Also, even when my application is run from the home screen, it will still ocationally quit in the background from what I assume to be the system quitting the application for additional resources. Even though my application is made to restore the service when it begins again, it never seems to restart after it quits (usually after 3 to 4 hours of background activity).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a BroadcastReceiver for the [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) Intent to detect when the device is booted. This requires the [RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) permission.

Instead of using a bound Service you can use a started [sticky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) Service. However, depending on what exactly you want to do, you might want to check if [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) suits your requirements better (maybe in combination with an IntentService, cf. [cwac-wakeful](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)).

Comment: Yeah, @cygery has it exactly right: you can't.  Running forever probably isn't what you want, anyway, though.  You want to do something periodically or in response to some change in the environment (inbound tickle, change in location, whatever) or something like that.  You *can* do any of those things.

Comment: I'm using a bound service that's "started" with AlarmManager. Is there something more reliable? This is also something that happens every 120ish seconds and polls a server.